# What linux kernel C function schedule () appears "need_resched:" mean

Tags: linux, scheduling

```
need_resched:
preempt_disable();
cpu = smp_processor_id();
rq = cpu_rq(cpu);
rcu_note_context_switch(cpu);
prev = rq->curr;
switch_count = &prev->nivcsw;

release_kernel_lock(prev);
```

I would like to ask is: "need_resched:" What is the role.

In detail，The linux kernel version is 2.6.35.3.

Answer (score 0):

`need_schedule:` is simply a label. Later in the code you will find:

```
if (need_resched())
    goto need_resched;
```

I.e., if the rescheduling flag ist set (what is tested by `need_reschedule()`), this point in code is executed (again).